# Rails + Passenger on Heroku: How to set expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, nginx, passenger

I'm using Rails api with an angularjs front-end which is served simply as static files under `public` directory. I've chosen passenger as the app server, deployed to heroku and everything seems to be working fine except for caching.

Since static assets are served by passenger/nginx, I believe this has nothing to do with rails. But I have no idea how to get it working or where to add configurations.

Response headers when requesting a static file (**application-a24e9c3607.js**):

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 06:45:31 GMT
Etag: "5696ce02-43102"
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Jan 2016 22:21:54 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this:

create [nginx.conf.erb](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/intro.html#nginx-configuration-template) file:

```
cp $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb nginx.conf.erb
```

Inside `server` block in **nginx.conf.erb**, instruct Nginx to generate appropriate headers  when a file under our assets directory is requested:

```
server {
  # ....

  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
}
```

Pass [Nginx engine options](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#nginx-engine-options) to passenger in Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size 3 --nginx-config-template nginx.conf.erb
```